# I need to connect to Object Storage using Pyspark in OCI is there any straight forward connector or sample example which I can refer

Tags: cloud, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I want to access data in my Object Storage using Pyspark with help of Jupyter notebook.

Whatever I have figured so far looking documents is it is a two step approach 
1. HDFS connector to Object Storage 
https://docs.cloud.oracle.com/iaas/Content/API/SDKDocs/hdfsconnector.htm

2.HDFS connector to Spark and submit my spark jobs 
https://docs.cloud.oracle.com/iaas/Content/API/SDKDocs/hdfsconnectorspark.htm

I am not finding any documents or an alternate SDK where I directly connect to Object store access run my spark job

Answer (score 2):

Are you running stand-alone Spark or do you have a backing Hadoop cluster with HDFS?

For Hadoop, you can leverage the OCI HDFS connector if you are using Apache Hadoop.
With Hadoop ISVs (Cloudera, Hortonworks, MapR) you will need to leverage [S3 compatability API](https://docs.cloud.oracle.com/iaas/Content/Identity/Tasks/managingcredentials.htm#Working2).  The OCI HDFS connector is not yet native to Hadoop (but has been commited to Apache upstream).   It works in single threaded mode with these ISVs, but not parallelized.   Single threaded performance is not optimal, as access to Object Storage has a per-thread cap.

For stand-alone spark, refer to [this documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/cloud-integration.html) leveraging S3 compat.

Answer (score 1):

Using the HDFS connector is one option, you may also want to look at the Storage Gateway appliance, which will present an Object Storage bucket as an NFS share, allowing any application to have read/write access (Subject to the security policy you apply) - see [Storage Documentation](https://docs.cloud.oracle.com/iaas/Content/StorageGateway/Concepts/storagegatewayoverview.htm) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ocifs

docs here: https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/tools/ocifs-sdk/latest/index.html

If you're running on OCI DataScience service, you would typically be authenticated with Resource Principal, so you can directly call the OCI Object Storage uri scheme

like:

```
df = sc.read.csv('oci://<bucket>@<tenancy_namespace>/folder/my_pattern*.csv',
                  header=True, inferSchema=True)
```